# Unity hold touch move horizontally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, touch

I have no idea how to start this, I want to move my character left and right when holding the touch.

Like in this game:

[Example Game - Stairs from Ketchapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNBDK.png)

[image]

I have only my script that detects the left or right space of the screen.

```
public float forwardSpeed = 5f;
public float sideSpeed = 5f;

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 deltaPosition = transform.forward * forwardSpeed;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Vector3 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        if (touchPosition.x > Screen.width * 0.5f)
            deltaPosition += transform.right * sideSpeed;
        else
            deltaPosition -= transform.right * sideSpeed;
    }
    transform.position += deltaPosition * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Other game what makes what I try is this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigframes.color_road

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me. Its used in a simple block breaker game to move a paddle left or right.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0){
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        int direction = (touch.position.x > (Screen.width / 2)) ? 1 : -1;
        MovePaddle(direction);
    }

}

void MovePaddle(int direction){
    float xPos = transform.position.x + (direction * Time.deltaTime * paddleSpeed);
    playerPos = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp (xPos, -8f, 8f), -9.5f, 0f);
    transform.position = playerPos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is the thing I already had. This script halfs the sceen from the left and right side but not like in the example I posted.

Answer (score 1):

i think that what you are trying to say is to only move when you are pressing the screen, not?
maybe this might help you:

```
public float forwardSpeed = 5f;
public float sideSpeed = 5f;

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 deltaPosition = transform.forward * forwardSpeed;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Vector3 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        if (touchPosition.x > Screen.width * 0.5f)
            deltaPosition += transform.right * sideSpeed;
        else
            deltaPosition -= transform.right * sideSpeed;
    }
    else{
            deltaPosition = sideSpeed;
    }
    transform.position += deltaPosition * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

pd: not tested because yet

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that is not really smooth

```
public float speed = 5;
public Rigidbody rb;

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    //Add touch support
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        h = touch.deltaPosition.x;
    }

    //Move only if we actually pressed something
    if (h > 0 || h < 0)
    {
        Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(h, 0, 0);
        tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        //rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + tempVect);

        Vector3 newPos = rb.transform.position + tempVect;
        checkBoundary(newPos);
    }
}

void checkBoundary(Vector3 newPos)
{
    //Convert to camera view point
    Vector3 camViewPoint = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(newPos);

    //Apply limit
    camViewPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.x, 0.04f, 0.96f);
    camViewPoint.y = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.y, 0.07f, 0.93f);

    //Convert to world point then apply result to the target object
    Vector3 finalPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(camViewPoint);
    rb.MovePosition(finalPos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Start()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);

         transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + t.deltaPosition.x * .02f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z );
    }
}
```

You can use this. Simple :)